# Sencha Tap listener not firing

Tags: javascript, button, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a test application with a couple of views. I am trying to invoke a simple 'tap' listener on my buttons. Even though the controller is instantiated and launched, the tap event does not seem to fire.

Here's my app.js

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',

    requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox',
        'Ext.form.FormPanel',
        'Ext.navigation.View'
    ],

    views: [
        'Main',
        'Tasks'
    ],

    controllers: [
        'Main'
    ],

    models: [
        'Task',
        'Schedule'
    ],

    stores: [
        'Tasks',
        'Schedules'
    ],

    launch: function() {
        // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
        try{
            Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();
        }catch(err){
            console.warn("[CUSTOMWARN]Could not destroy loading indicator because of -- \n"+err);
        }

        var DEBUG=false;
        if(!DEBUG){
            // Initialize the main view
            Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('MyApp.view.Main'));
        }
    }
});
```

Main.js -- controller

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    requires: [
        'MyApp.view.Main'
    ],
    init: function(){
        // download and parse data from server here.
        console.log('controller initiated!');
    },
    config: {
        refs: {
            loginBtn: 'button[action=login]'
        },
        control: {
            loginBtn: {
                tap: 'loginBtnHandler'
            }
        }
    },
    loginBtnHandler: function(){
        this.callParent(arguments); 
        Ext.Msg.alert('here');
    }
});
```

Main.js -- view

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    alias: 'customnavigationview',
    requires: [
        'MyApp.form.Login'
    ],
    config: {
        navigationBar: {
            hidden: true
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'logincard',
                flex: 1
            }
        ],        
    }
});
```

Login.js -- for xtype: 'logincard'

```
Ext.define('MyApp.form.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'logincard',
    requires: [
        'Ext.field.Password',
        'Ext.field.Email',
        'Ext.form.FieldSet',
        'Ext.field.Toggle',
        'Ext.Label'
    ],
    // id: 'loginForm',
    config: {
        items: [
            {

                xtype         : 'label',
                html          : 'Login failed. Please enter correct credentials.',
                itemId        : 'signInFailedLabel',
                hidden        : true,
                hideAnimation : 'fadeOut',
                showAnimation : 'fadeIn',
                style         : 'color:#990000;',
                margin        : 10
            },
            {
                title: 'Please log in',
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                items:[
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name : 'username',
                        label: 'UserName'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'passwordfield',
                        name : 'password',
                        label: 'Password'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                items: [
                    {                
                        xtype : 'togglefield',
                        name  : 'rememberLogin',
                        label : 'Remember Me '
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype    : 'button',
                id       : 'loginSubmitBtn',
                itemId   : 'loginSubmitItemBtn',
                text     : 'Login',
                ui       : 'action',
                action   : 'login',
                margin   : 10
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

**EDIT:** So I tried to use `Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#loginSubmitBtn")` and on printing the output on console, I can see that it is pointing to the correct button. Here's the output.

```
0: Class
_badgeCls: "x-badge"
_baseCls: "x-button"
_disabledCls: "x-item-disabled"
_floatingCls: "x-floating"
_hasBadgeCls: "x-hasbadge"
_hiddenCls: "x-item-hidden"
_icon: false
_iconAlign: "left"
_itemId: "loginSubmitItemBtn"
_labelCls: "x-button-label"
_margin: 10
_pressedCls: "x-button-pressing"
_pressedDelay: 0
_styleHtmlCls: "x-html"
_text: "Login"
_ui: "action"
action: "login"
badgeElement: Class
bodyElement: Class
config: objectClass
currentUi: "x-button-action"
element: Class
eventDispatcher: Class
getEventDispatcher: function () {
getId: function () {
getObservableId: function () {
getUniqueId: function () {
iconElement: Class
id: "loginSubmitBtn"
initConfig: function (){}
initialConfig: Object
initialized: true
innerElement: Class
managedListeners: Object
observableId: "#loginSubmitBtn"
onInitializedListeners: Array[0]
parent: Class
referenceList: Array[4]
refreshFloating: function () {
refreshSizeState: function () {
renderElement: Class
rendered: true
textElement: Class
usedSelectors: Array[1]
__proto__: Object
length: 1
```

**EDIT 3: ** Found it! See answer here: [Sencha Tap listener not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158796/sencha-tap-listener-not-firing/17172747#17172747)

Comment: No error in the console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is weird, but I found out why my buttonclick was not being handled properly. I usually use Google Chrome as my testing browser with web inspector on. I downloaded Safari and tried the same code and it worked like its supposed to. I looked at both the browsers, and the only difference was that Chrome had web inspector on, while Safari didn't. I closed the web inspector in Chrome and the button handler worked great (without reloading). I restarted the browser, pushed the inspector to a separate window, none of them worked. However, Safari works great even with inspector on. Probably a Chrome bug?

Google Chrome version: 27.0.1453.110

**EDIT: ** I had the touch emulation turned on in the web inspector. With this turned on, we have to close the web inspector for the touch event to register. Otherwise, we have to turn off the touch emulation to register for the events while the web inspector is open.

**TL;DR: Close your web inspector in Chrome before testing, if you have touch emulation turned on.**

Answer (score 1):

The listener for a button tap should be just 'tap' instead of 'itemtap'

```
tap: 'loginBtnHandler'
```

Hope it helps-

Comment: my bad. It was 'tap' in the beginning. I have edited my question.

Comment: ok, and are your sure the ref selector is finding the correct item? loginBtn: 'button[action=login]'. I would go with an itemId approach, just to make sure.

Comment: just replace: loginBtn: 'button[action=login]' with ie: loginBtn: 'logincard #loginSubmitItemBtn'

Comment: I tried that actually, it didn't work. Then I tried the action=login way, which didn't work either. Unfortunately, none of them throw any exception or warnings otherwise I could have given you more information.

Comment: thats weird.. did you try with the id? 'loginSubmitBtn', that should work-

Answer (score 1):

I think I've had this problem in the past. Try qualifying the ref in the controller with the view name to narrow the query down:

```
loginBtn: 'logincard button[action=login]'
```

Comment: tried this as well... unfortunately, this doesn't work either. Is there a debugging process that I might go through to narrow the problem down? (Sorry, I am quite new to Sencha Touch)

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17172747/1140134 looks like it wasn't the code issue after all.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best, but should work:

First remove the tap listener on the controller. Also remove the 'action' property on the button, and set the handler on the button:

```
{
    xtype    : 'button',
    id       : 'loginSubmitBtn',
    itemId   : 'loginSubmitItemBtn',
    text     : 'Login',
    ui       : 'action',
    //action   : 'login',
    margin   : 10,
    handler  : function () {
        MyApp.app.getController('Main').loginBtnHandler()
    }
}
```

Comment: But this will break the MVC paradigm, which I don't want to do. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: I removed the:
  action   : 'login',
in your code and it works

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17172747/1140134

removing action: 'login' still didn't work with the inspector on.